# Is it possible to run script while stopping docker container?

Tags: signals, docker

I want to run some script inside the container when I execute the

```
docker stop ${ContainerName}
```

Is there any way of achieving that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question man.

First of all, `docker stop` sends a kind `SIGTERM` to the root process inside your container. And by default, your process has ten seconds before Docker send a no-mercy `SIGKILL`, killing it. [[1]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/)

Second, a robust application shouldn't corrupt data if the process was unexpectedly killed. For example, Nginx has well documented way to handle system signals. [[2]](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html)

But in case your're making your onw application, and that might be even a Shell script, you'll need to implement your own signal handling. Just a few lines of code and you're done. Here's a nice tutorial. [[3]](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/)

Have a nice day.